# Embedding a dialogfragment containing a gridview leads to unscrollable gridview showing only it's first row

Tags: android, gridview, android-dialogfragment, viewstub

I have a `DialogFragment` containing a `Gridview`. Showing it as dialog works as expected. Now, I try to embed the same `DialogFragment` in an `Activity` For that, I have a `ViewStub` in my `Activity` layout defined as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout>
<!-- Other children -->

    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/view_stub"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inflatedId="@+id/attachment"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Note that I have not specified the inflated layout here. Depending on the `Intent` extras this `Activity`  is started with, it can inflate one of several layouts into this stub, one of them being a placeholder for the `DialogFragment`:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>
```

After checking for proper `Intent` extras, I inflate the above layout and add the `DialogFragment` with the following code:

```
viewStub.setLayoutResource( R.layout.dialog_fragment_placeholder );
flPlaceHolder = ( FrameLayout ) viewStub.inflate();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add( flPlaceHolder.getId(),
                DialogFragment.newInstance( //arguments ),
                DialogFragment.TAG )
        .commit();
```

This leads to the `DialogFragment` being added, but the `GridView` shows only the first row and is not scrollable. In case it's needed here's the layout of the `DialogFragment`

```
<GridView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#cc000000"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent">

</GridView>
```

I am pretty sure the issue is because of improper `layout_height`/`layout_width` attributes in one of the layouts, but I tried messing around with all possible values in all possible files without any good results. Any help?